# Animation in Excel charts not shown

Tags: excel, vba

The idea is I build a scatter chart x in A2:A11, y in B2:B11. Formulas in B:B are parametric on cell $F$2. My macro:

```
  Sub AnimateLinear()
    For i = 1 to 100 step 0.1
      Range("F2").value = sin(i)
      Application.Wait Now
    Next i
  End Sub
```

And I expect this to produce an oscillation of the line in the chart, but nothing is shown except the final result. Something that has always worked for me until I installed a Student edition of Excel. My code kept working at school's computers but not in my laptop. Today I installed Office Pro 2019 and it still is not working. I have looked in the options to no avail. Anyone can enlighten please?

Comment: `Application.Wait Now` looks off. Should be `Now` plus some increment.

Comment: Hi, I haven't used `Application.Wait Now` before but looking at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait it suggests that it pauses the macro until a specified time. Since you are giving `Now` is it possible now has already happened and its waiting 24hrs until the same time again. Does changing to `Second(Now()) + 1` help?